# How to read Json array in jquery in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel-5

I am using ajax-jquery to fetch multiple eloquent objects in laravel 5.2

This is what i am getting as response in jquery

```
 {

 "screens":
 [{"screen_id":1,"screen_name":"Screen 1 ","screen_msg":"Hello","screen_status":"Active","cinema_id":1,"created_at":"2016-09-08 04:34:28","updated_at":"2016-09-08 04:34:28"}],

 "showtime":
  [{"show_id":6,"movie_id":1,"dimensional":"2D","cinema_id":1,"screen_id":1,"show_date":"2016-10-04","show_time":"00:57:00","show_status":"Active","created_at":"2016-09-08 12:21:06","updated_at":"2016-09-08 12:21:06"},
   {"show_id":7,"movie_id":1,"dimensional":"2D","cinema_id":1,"screen_id":1,"show_date":"2016-10-04","show_time":"00:57:00","show_status":"Active","created_at":"2016-09-08 12:22:15","updated_at":"2016-09-08 12:22:15"}]

 }
```

my controller function code

```
  public function getscreen($id)
{
    $screens=Movies_screen::where('cinema_id',$id)->get();
    $showtime=Movies_showtimes::where('cinema_id',$id)->get();

    return response()->json(['screens' => $screens, 'showtime' => $showtime]);
}
```

I am reading those json array in jquery as

```
  $("#cinemahall").on("change click",function(){

var cinema_id=$("#cinemahall option:selected").val();
//ajax
    $.get('/askspidy/admin/showtime/getscreen/' + cinema_id, function(data){

        $("#screenname").empty();
        $("#screenname").append('<option value=0>Select Screen</option>');

        $.each(data,function(index,screenobj){
            $("#screenname").append('<option value="' +screenobj.screens[0].screen_id + '">' +screenobj.screens[0].screen_name +'</option>');
        });
    });
});
```

In console i can see proper data without any error but i am unable to access each and every field of json response using

```
 screenobj.screens[0].screen_name
```

Need help to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `data.screens[0].screen_name` you don't need the loop

or

```
 $.each(data.screens,function(index,screenobj){
            $("#screenname").append('<option value="' +screenobj.screen_id + '">' +screenobj.screen_name +'</option>');
        });
```

Comment: your second option worked well for me , because i may get multiple rows from controller function, and this code works for single row as well as multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can read screens data as mentioned below

```
 $("#screenname").empty();
        $("#screenname").append('<option value=0>Select Screen</option>');

 $.each(data.screens,function(index,screenobj){
            $("#screenname").append('<option value="' +screenobj.screen_id + '">' +screenobj.screen_name +'</option>');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `data` you're getting is not an Object.

You will need to pass the `dataType` along with the `.get()` request or convert the returned data into `JS Object` using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Look [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get-url-data-success-dataType) for syntax to define the DataType along with sending request.

To parse the plain string to JS object like this,

```
var data=JSON.parse(data);
```